# Why is traceroute showing a private IP address between the router and the WAN router?

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have a TP-Link Router (TL-R605), connected on the LAN to a TP-Link switch, and connected to the WAN directly to my internet provider router (ZTE F670L).

The TP-Link router has an IP address of 192.168.0.1, and my computers sits under the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet, with DHCP enabled at the TP-Link router.

The ZTE router has an IP address of 192.168.1.1, and the TP-Link router WAN port gets a static IP address of 192.168.1.2. DCHP is disabled on the ZTE router.

It seems that when I'm tracing a route, the TP-Link router does a hop to a **169.254.11.21 address**, instead of going directly to 192.168.1.1. I have not manually added any routing rules.

```
user@home:~$ traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.280 ms  0.223 ms  0.191 ms
 2  169.254.11.21 (169.254.11.21)  0.881 ms  0.993 ms  0.853 ms
 3  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  1.066 ms  0.775 ms  1.105 ms
 4  172.31.255.1 (172.31.255.1)  7.256 ms  7.224 ms  2.032 ms
 5  172.21.11.2 (172.21.11.2)  1.948 ms  1.969 ms  1.886 ms
 6  172.21.10.234 (172.21.10.234)  2.810 ms  3.154 ms  3.092 ms
 7  172.19.252.33 (172.19.252.33)  2.378 ms  3.214 ms  3.154 ms
 8  as28283.portoalegre.rs.ix.br (177.52.38.57)  3.116 ms  3.078 ms  3.305 ms
 9  as13335.portoalegre.rs.ix.br (177.52.38.200)  9.235 ms  9.203 ms  9.170 ms
10  one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1)  2.778 ms  2.747 ms  2.715 ms
```

This traceroute was run out of a Linux server inside the LAN (192.168.0.3), and no routes are manually added there as well:

```
user@home:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp2s0
```

So can someone please explain why it's hoping to 169.254 address and how can I remove it?

Comment: Do you get the same if connected directly to the ZTE router? (Keep in mind that traceroute doesn't show the address where TP-Link _sent_ the packet -- it shows the address which _replied_, and that's not always the same.)

Comment: 169.254.11.21 is probably an APIPA address.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same router.
From what I understand that extra hop is just caused by the DHCP server replying what IP to forward next

Answer (score -1):

and it sure is taking a long time inside the ER605 to access that internal hop in the ER605, which from what support says is necessary for the WAN/LAN port support, and this embedded and non published DHCP server starts passing out addresses
at 169.254.11.21/22... and so on for the WAN interface(s) despite having a STATIC IP address assigned to a WAN port.

Z

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106114)

Comment: Regarding the 169.254.11.21 address;  The ER605 will respond on the default WAN address despite the WAN port provisioned for a STATIC.  A simple test is to configure the ER605 by itself with a good IP assigned on the WAN with the default route pointing to the WAN port address, and it will ping successfully to that STATIC and also the 169.254.11.21 - I personally have BLOCKED that 169.254 B class from all interfaces and have been able to make it unreachable, because it will respond as the STATIC with the DHCP 169.254 mentioned previously.  WADesigned

Comment: This is the address of the reply from TP-LINK support provided to me by their support staff:  https://community.tp-link.com/en/business/forum/topic/506156